# Joomla Media Form Field - Only Images

Tags: php, joomla

In joomla 1.7, the form field with the type 'media' only allow to use images or it is possible  to use another type of media, like pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You really should upgrade to 2.5.4+ of Joomla! 1.6 -> 2.5 have significant security problems that have been patched in the 2.5.4.
2. There is also a form field type of `file` - you can find a [list of standard field types here](http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types).
3. If that doesn't help creating a custom field type is not too hard - we've made several for unique client requirements, start with [this article do Joomla! Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type).